# How to do a Horizontal looping in PHP

Tags: php, css, loops

The current loop below yields result as this:

```
<?php  
    foreach ($response->items->item as $value) {
        echo("<img src='".$value->imageUrl."' width=200><br>");
        echo($value->description."<br>");
        echo($value->url."<br>");
    };

?>
```

**//Result**

```
<1st row>
(image)
description
(url)
</end 1st row>

<2nd row>
(image)
description
(url)
</end 2nd row>

<3rd row>
(image)
description
(url)
</end 3rd row>
```

What I need to accomplish is Looping the result so each item is horizontal from left-to-right. e.g.

```
 <1st col>                 <2nd col>              <3rd col>
 (image)                   (image)                (image)
 description               description            description
 (url)                     (url)                  (url)
 </end 1st col>            </end 2nd col>         </end 3rd col>
```

The conditions should be:

1. each row as shown above, can only have 3 columns, as shown right above.
2. when there are more items, each item will display on the next row just like how it displays on  first row.

*What is an item?*

One Item includes:

```
 (image)
 description
 (url)
```

*How many items?*

It can be up to 20 or more.

> end of question

Ok, everyone, end of the question. Hope to get help with this, that is effective.

Comment: you need to remove <br> form echo. and apply some css to show in columns.

Comment: It's "thanks in advance". Put each item's content in a floating div, and use a CSS clearing attribute on every third item.

Comment: just a quick tips here. If you are trying to result an html code here why don't just try using div for each row and make that div float:left

Comment: yes, not a php issue, you should do that using css

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the warm responses, I'm slightly overwhelmed with the answers. Give me more time, I'd tick as answered soon, hopefully when I have time to work on this again, busy with another problem at the moment, but thanks for answering and correcting "Thanks in Advanced". I have to blame that English tutor.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a lot of things to accomplish it. The best way (I think..) is creating a UL and breaking at every third element:

```
<ul>
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($response->items->item as $value) : ?>
<li<?php if ( $i % 3 == 0 ) echo ' class="break"' ?>>
    <?php echo "<img src='".$value->imageUrl."' width=200><br>"; ?>
    <?php echo $value->description ?>
</li>
<?php $i++; // Increment counter
endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Then you need to specify that this list must be horizontal and specify to break the line in the .break elements:

```
<style>
ul li {
    float:left;
}
ul li.break {
    clear: right;
}
</style>
```

Comment: No need for 'break' class, proper way to do that is to set a width on ul

Comment: Well.. Imagine that you need a 320px UL with each LI with a width of 100px and a margin between them of 10px. The only way is to create the .break class, otherwise the list will break on each second element...

Comment: Then just set width to 360px. With your code, imagine you want to display 4 items/row : you will have to modify code even it is just a display issue.

Comment: When I said "you need a 320px UL" I meant that it should be of 320px. A 360px UL doesn't fit. Otherwise, you are right.. if it could be higher maybe it would be better to specify the UL width, so the adjustment will be automatic.

Answer (score 0):

I built this a little while ago for a client, I *think* it's exactly what you need:
[Column-focused Tables](http://www.digitalgemstones.com/code/tools/tables.php)

Basically, you modify the `addItem()` function to properly fit the data you want to display (links, images, etc.) and then just call `addItem()` for each item to display.  Then `outputItemTable()` will output a table with the data grouped together properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php  
        echo '<div style="width:100%;">';
        foreach ($response->items->item as $value) {
            echo('<div style="display:inline-block;">
<img src="'.$value->imageUrl.'" width=200><br>');
            echo($value->description."<br>");
            echo($value->url."</div>");
        };
        echo '</div>';

    ?>
```

i hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array();
$array[] = array('name'=>'Name 1', 'id'=>'w', 'spec'=>'rrr');
$array[] = array('name'=>'Name 2', 'id'=>'x', 'spec'=>'sss');
$array[] = array('name'=>'Name 3', 'id'=>'y', 'spec'=>'ttt');
$array[] = array('name'=>'Name 4', 'id'=>'z', 'spec'=>'uuu');

  function horizontal_table($array, $key){
    $count = count($array);
    $return = "";
    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
      $return .= "<td>";
      if(isset($array[$i][$key])){
        if(!empty($array[$i][$key])){
          $return .= $array[$i][$key];
        } else {
          $return .= "&nbsp;";
        }
      } else {
        $return .= "&nbsp;";
      }
      $return .= "</td>";
    }
    return $return;     
  }
?>

<table border="1px solid #000">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <?php echo horizontal_table($array, 'name'); ?>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item Id</td>
    <?php echo horizontal_table($array, 'id'); ?>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item Spec</td>
    <?php echo horizontal_table($array, 'spec'); ?>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is how i do it.